# Boy goes on a space mission with a human-like dog partner and encounters a lizard planet

Tags: story-identification, novel, childrens-novel, astronauts, space-travel

This book was part of a series. It was aimed towards children or young adults. Nothing violent or gory. My assumption is that it was written somewhere around 2010 as it is not an old book. It's written in English and is probably British or American. It is not a show, a TV series, or a cartoon. It is a series of books.

The protagonist is a boy sent on a space mission alongside a talking, bipedal, humanoid-looking dog or wolf/canine on a planet. The dog is not actually his pet and does not belong to him. He is actually assigned to serve as a partner during the mission. He remains his partner throughout the sequels of the book.

The boy is presumably 12 years of age. Not too old, not too young. His partner is outwardly friendly and outgoing while the boy is a bit brash and energetic. The boy likes fast food while his partner likes steak and other kinds of meat. The boy lives with his (single?) mother.

The organization responsible for sending the pair on a mission is a space school or academy for young astronauts or space explorers.

Briefly, there is a part in the book where the boy takes on an exam/quiz/assignment related to space before taking on the mission. Instead of being written on paper, it is holographic or being on an IPad-like device that's described as being futuristic in design.

The pair encounters a planet inhabited by black, scaly lizard-like aliens that are aggressive and hostile. They are shown in the cover to stand upright yet are described as being smaller than the protagonists. They have spikes/ osteoderms like an iguana or a crocodile/alligator running down their backs, with sharp claws on their hands and feet. They resemble house geckoes.

Upon encountering these creatures the protagonists are attacked by them. They remain hostile towards them until the pair escape the planet.

The book has a few illustrations in black and white but normally isn't reliant on them. The cover of the book depicts three of the lizard-like aliens watching a rocket take off in the sky, with the middle one glancing back over its shoulder at the readers.
The cover is in 3D while the illustrations in the book are 2D.

Comment: You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/tips-for-asking-story-identification-questions) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, what was the boy's name? What was his dog's name? Could the dog speak? Were the aliens aggressive to the boy? Did they attack him? Were they violent? Was this book aimed at adults (with gore/explicit violence/sex) or something more sedate? What was the name of the planet? Who sent him on this mission? Why would anyone send a boy on a space mission? How did he get there? Did he land or did he crash?

Comment: This book is aimed towards children or young adults. Nothing violent or gory.

Comment: Did you read it in English? Who was the author? When did you read it? How old was the boy?

Comment: I don't remember any of the details and neither do I remember the author's name. It definitely was in English. I do recall that I read it way back sometime around 2015, I think. I presume the boy was about 12 years of age. Not too old, not too young.

Comment: Don't forget to [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/283725/edit) that into your question

Comment: I do have one detail I remember, and it is from the second book. He competes in his next mission with a girl whose last name is Montenegro.

Comment: https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolars_phantastische_Abenteuer A 12 yo boy and his talking dog have a blow-up-spaceship and travel each night from the hous' roof into space. Wikipedia has no english website, sorry.

Comment: found the English article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_M%C3%A9zga_Family Part "The Adventures of Aladár Mézga"

Comment: I don't think that's actually the story.

Comment: Is it [Galaxy Zack](https://www.simonandschuster.com/series/Galaxy-Zack)?

Comment: Not really, but I think it's close. The few illustrations in the book are 2D but the cover is 3D, unlike Galaxy Zack.